# Cannot find module 'node:events' error thrown when running discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, discord.js

Here is my basic source code, I'm just trying to get the bot online:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', ()=> {
    console.log('Bot is online')
});

client.login('token');
```

When I run the program it throws an error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
- D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
```

'D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js',
'D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js',
'D:\Eclipse\Workspace\discordbot\src\main.js'
]
}

I'm currently have node 17.0.0, and using Eclipse. Node is in my path environment. My package JSON file is:

```
{
  "name": "discordbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.2.0",
    "node": "^17.0.0"
 }
}
```

I have looked at similar issues and none of the answers seemed to have fixed the issue. Discord says that v 16.10.0 or higher will work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that you use NodeJS v17? Usually the Node Version is now included in stack traces. What does `node --version` yield?

Comment: Yes, it shows V17.0.0.

Comment: You seem to [this package called node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) installed instead of actually having node.js v17.0.0. Try uninstalling node.js and installing the right version again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade node you need to install it globally, not just within the current package. Typically this is done by [downloading the installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), or by using your [preferred package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).